# <li class=disabled not working for disable an option in the menu

Tags: c#, css

I will like to know how to disable ChoiceC from this menu if the user is not logon to the
current site using the loging page.

The ChoiceC option will be only available to the user which have connected to the site had been approved.
Can you provide me link or example on how to perform this task with C# ?
I tried to had the class="disabled" but it didn't do anything ie the option is still available.

```
<div id="menu"> 
    <ul id="menua"; class="ul menua">
    <li style="text-align:center;padding:9px;" class="smallwhitetext"></li> 
        <li><a href="../pages/ChoiceA.aspx">ChoiceA</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">MenuA</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="../pages/MenuAoption1.aspx">option 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="../pages/MenuAoption2.aspx">option 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="../pages/ChoiceB.aspx">Choice B</a></li>
        <li class="disabled">
            <a href="../pages/ChoiceC.aspx">Choice C</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Even if you can disable a `<li>`, there's something else you should consider:  Anyone who hits F12 in their browser and edits that `<li>` element and removes the `<disabled>` attribute will then have access to that attribute.

If you have server code that is tracking if the user logged in, the only way you can securely make sure that the user doesn't enable this item themselves is *never provide it in the first place*.  Edit your code that generates this stuff to check for login, and if not, never emit the option for ChoiceC.

Comment: I got an error  Validation (XHTML5): Attribute disabled is not a valid attribute of element 'li'

Comment: @ScottMermelstein, I realized what was being asked after the edit and removed my comment.

Comment: @valverij I don't think the user has realized what's being asked yet.  :-)

Comment: Should we have to Default pages ?  ex.:  defaultA for all user and Default B will be only for authorized users ?   What I don't like in this it will be the exact same page + 1 more option in the menu for the authorized people.

Comment: Are you using ASP.net MVC or WebForms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ul id="menua"; class="ul menua">
   <li><a href="../pages/OptionA.aspx">Option A</a></li>
   <li><a href="../pages/OptionB.aspx">Option B</a></li>
   <% if(userIdAuthenticated) {  %>
      <li><a href="../pages/OptionC.aspx">Option C</a> </li>'
   <% } %> 
</ul>
```

This is working but still have a small error.
The only error I got is the top ul which is underline in green with the following error message Validation (XHTML5)  Text is not allowed between the opening and closing tag for element ul.

Comment: The validation error is because of the semicolon. Remove that and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend a two-step approach.  First, don't have the C# code output the link in the list item if they're not logged in.  Second, change the style of the list item by applying a class to that item to indicate to the user that they're not logged in and thus the item is unavailable.

Simply applying a class to that item wont work.

Comment: can you provide me an example or a link to resolve my issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what method you use to build the menu and choices, but normally this could best be done when the page is generated at the server. Just wrap your conditional choice inside an if-statement where you check the approval. Here is some pseudo code for the old style:

```
<ul>
  <li>ChoiceA</li>
  <li>MenuA
    <ul>
      <li>option 1</li>
      <li>option 2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>ChoiceB</li>
  <% if( userIsAuthenticated) { %>
  <li>ChoiceC</li>
  <% } %>
</ul>
```

Now I know there are many ways to go about outputting HMTL with MVCs and templates and stuff, but since you didn't mention any specific technique I went for the old style.

Hope it helps!

**EDIT**

You could also skip the mixing of C# and HTML like one used to do in ASP and still do in PHP and others by simply:

```
if(userIsAuthenticated) {
    Response.Write(@"<li><a href=""your link"">Choice C</a></li>");
}
```

The downside is that when you get a lot of quotes its easier to miss some and a bit harder to read. Plus you wont get code coloring for the HTML.

**Note:** The `@` is for verbatim string literals which escape every special character except quotes. You escape these using double quotes instead of the usual `\`.

Comment: <% System.Activities.Statements.If userIsAuthenticated; %>
     <li> <a href="../pages/ChoiceC.aspx">Choice C</a> </li>
  <% End if %>  I got an error with the end if  "Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await an new object expressions can be used as statement   I am using VS 2013 express.

Comment: Sorry, my bad! I was thinking ASP, not C#. Perhaps `<% if(userIdAuthenticated) { %><li>...</li><% } %>` will be better. Haven't used C# in that way personally, never did go the full way over from ASP. -- Updated my answer to reflect --

Comment: This is working but still have a small error. The only error I got is the top ul which is underline in green with the following error message Validation (XHTML5) Text is not allowed between the opening and closing tag for element ul.

Comment: Hm... can't see any text outside <li></li> so there shouldn't be raised an error like that... Perhaps some artifacts around the c# code block?

Comment: I have problem to set the variable userIsAuthenticated. When in put it in the public partial class MasterPage it always overriding if I set it to true somewhere else.  I need to declare it in the master page .cs because I give an error if I don't.  Can you explain me the trick on how to set it and where ?  Thanks

Comment: I am using the variable userIsAuthenticated in the MasterPage.master. The default value should be set to false.   Then when I go to the login page and the authentification is OK the set the value to true.  The problem is the value true is not sent back to the MasterPage.master.

Comment: I'm not super familiar with VC#, but how will session variables work for you for storing this? `Session["userIsAuthenticated"] = false;` <-- Set this when initializing the page for the user for the first time.
When the user has logged in set it to true. Check it with `bool authed = (bool)Session["userIsAuthenticated"]; if(authed == true) { ... }`